# "Refresh Status" of Source Control toolbar in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have VS 2010 with extension VS2P4 for using Perforce commands within Visual Studio.
There is a nice "Refresh Status" button on Source Control toolbar.

[image]

But that icon updates only the current project, not the other projects.
So I need always to select the solution node in Solution Explorer before I click "Refresh Status".

Is it possible to update all projects with one click without selecting solution node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today's version, 1.74, that's the way it works. Refresh Status will refresh all icons in the solution, regardless of what node in Solution Explorer is selected.